# Not sure of settings of Exchange server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, exchange

I need some help with Exchange server settings, I really do not have much time for studying right now, so please help.

I have simple Windows Small Business server 2000 with Exchange and DNS installed.

1. what DNS servers should I set in Properties of network connection? (local IP, or remote ISP DNS servers?)
2. my exchange server is becoming victim of SPAM attacks. How can I disable anonymous remote delivery and enable authentication with valid username/password ?
3. as I receive too much of spam, my BadMail directory (almost 20,000 spams) is growing up, how can I limit its size?
4. the delays between sending and receiving from/to local address are quite big - 10-15 minutes. How can I avoid this? - I assume this could be resolved by enabling authentication so that spam could disappear.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a question for ServerFault instead of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

I Realise this is a very old question but in case there are other out there wondering!

1. DHCP should pass out your SBS server as the DNS server - Your SBS server's DNS forwarder should be set to forward out to your ISP or another public DNS server I.E Googles: 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4
2. To stop spam attacks ensure your server is not setup as an open relay - Check to see if you have SMTP feed and restrict firewall access to the server providing your SMTP feed.
3. If you still recive alot of spam and wish to take away the overhead of keeping ontop of this look for a hosted spam solution such as Microsoft Forefront. (Many other benefits of this to!)
4. The delays could be caused either from lack of bandwidth due to SPAM (Check your SMTP Q's), the method of sending I.E DNS. If your server downloads email via POP3 10-15 minutes will be set on your POP3 connector.